# Custom icon with Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, markers, icon

I'm trying to add custom icon in Leaflet, but it doesn't show on map.

This is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        function fc_MapMod_initialize_99()
        {
            var locations = [ ['<h4 class="fleximaptitle">[copy] test feature</h4><p>Marseille, France</p> <p class=\"link\"><a href=\"/flexi-dev/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&amp;view=item&amp;cid=8&amp;id=11&amp;Itemid=126\" target=\"\">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_READMORE_TXT</a></p> <div class="directions"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Marseille,+France&ftid=0x12c9bf4344da5333:0x40819a5fd970220" target="_blank" class="direction">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_DIRECTIONNAME_TXT</a></div>',43.296482,5.36978,'http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/army.png']
,['<h4 class="fleximaptitle">[copy] test feature</h4><p>Paris, France</p> <p class=\"link\"><a href=\"/flexi-dev/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&amp;view=item&amp;cid=8&amp;id=12&amp;Itemid=126\" target=\"\">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_READMORE_TXT</a></p> <div class="directions"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Paris,+France&ftid=0x47e66e1f06e2b70f:0x40b82c3688c9460" target="_blank" class="direction">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_DIRECTIONNAME_TXT</a></div>',48.856614,2.3522219,'http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/accesdenied.png']
,['<h4 class="fleximaptitle">NY test feature</h4><p>New York, État de New York, États-Unis</p> <p class=\"link\"><a href=\"/flexi-dev/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&amp;view=item&amp;cid=8&amp;id=13&amp;Itemid=126\" target=\"\">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_READMORE_TXT</a></p> <div class="directions"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=New+York,+%C3%89tat+de+New+York,+%C3%89tats-Unis&ftid=0x89c24fa5d33f083b:0xc80b8f06e177fe62" target="_blank" class="direction">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_DIRECTIONNAME_TXT</a></div>',40.7127753,-74.0059728,'http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/air_fixwing.png']
,['<h4 class="fleximaptitle">test feature</h4><p>82 Rue de Fenouillet, 31200 Toulouse, France</p> <p class=\"link\"><a href=\"/flexi-dev/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&amp;view=item&amp;cid=8&amp;id=3&amp;Itemid=126\" target=\"\">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_READMORE_TXT</a></p> <div class="directions"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=82+Rue+de+Fenouillet,+31200+Toulouse,+France&ftid=0x12aea4ca3e8f6c0b:0x26677de5987f1b9a" target="_blank" class="direction">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_DIRECTIONNAME_TXT</a></div>',43.6320424,1.4229078,'http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/banners/osmbanner1.png']
,['<h4 class="fleximaptitle">tokyo [copy] test feature</h4><p>Tokyo, Japon</p> <p class=\"link\"><a href=\"/flexi-dev/index.php?option=com_flexicontent&amp;view=item&amp;cid=8&amp;id=10&amp;Itemid=126\" target=\"\">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_READMORE_TXT</a></p> <div class="directions"><a href="https://maps.google.com/?q=Tokyo,+Japon&ftid=0x60188b857628235d:0xcdd8aef709a2b520" target="_blank" class="direction">FLEXI_GOOGLEMAP_DIRECTIONNAME_TXT</a></div>',35.6803997,139.7690174,'http://localhost/flexi-dev/\images/icons-map/bats.png']
  ];

            var markerClusters;
            var markers = [];

            var lat = 48.852969;
            var lon = 2.349903;

            theMap_99 = L.map('fc_module_map_99').setView([lat, lon], 11);
            markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({ disableClusteringAtZoom: 15,removeOutsideVisibleBounds:true,animate:true, maxClusterRadius :50 });          // Title display
            L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
            {
                // Datas sources
                attribution: 'OPENSTREETMAP_ATTRIBUTION_TXT',
                minZoom: 1,
                maxZoom: 15         })
            .addTo(theMap_99);

            var customMarkerIcons = [];
            var iconCounter = 0;

            customMarkerIcons[0] = L.icon({
                iconUrl: 'https://mts.googleapis.com/vt/icon/name=icons/spotlight/spotlight-waypoint-b.png?text=A&psize=16&font=fonts/arialuni_t.ttf&color=ff330000&scale=1&ax=44&ay=48',
                iconSize: [40, 67],
                iconAnchor: [25, 67],
                popupAnchor: [-3, -67]
            });

            for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++)
            {

                marker = new L.marker(
                    [locations[i][1],
                    locations[i][2]]
                    ,{icon:locations[i][3]}             )
                    .bindPopup(locations[i][0])

                markerClusters.addLayer(marker);                markers.push(marker);

                // We only have a limited number of possible icon colors, so rewind icon index when icons finish
                iconCounter = iconCounter >= customMarkerIcons.length ? 0 : iconCounter + 1;
            }
            var group = new L.featureGroup(markers);

            theMap_99.addLayer(markerClusters);
            theMap_99.fitBounds(group.getBounds().pad(0.5));
        }

        // Initialize the Map
        fc_MapMod_initialize_99();
    </script>
```

Comment: Are there any errors on the [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) from your browser's dev tools?

Comment: the console say
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.fr/osmfr/{z}/{x}/{y}.png',
   {
    // Datas sources
    attribution: 'OPENSTREETMAP_ATTRIBUTION_TXT',<= here
but realy here i this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have error in specifying icon when creating marker. Insted of icon object you are giving `iconUrl`.

First you have create the icon and then use it in marker creation. It should look something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  customMarkerIcon = L.icon({
      iconUrl: locations[i][3],
      iconSize: [40, 67],
      iconAnchor: [25, 67],
      popupAnchor: [-3, -67]
  });

  marker = new L.marker(
      [locations[i][1],
      locations[i][2]]
      ,{icon: customMarkerIcon})
      .bindPopup(locations[i][0])

  markerClusters.addLayer(marker);
  markers.push(marker);

  iconCounter = iconCounter >= customMarkerIcons.length ? 0 : iconCounter + 1;
}
```

Comment: hello thanks for return !
if use your code its realy better but i didn't have icons
i have this error
`house.html?start=10:742 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '3' of undefined
    at fc_MapMod_initialize_129 (house.html?start=10:742)
    at house.html?start=10:770`

Comment: forgot mistake ... that soved :!!!!!!!